# Find family set $\{E_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ where $E_k\subseteq \Bbb R$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find family set $\{E_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ where $E_k\subseteq \Bbb R$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$, and satisfy the property. And prove your results.

$$\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}E_k=\Bbb R\ \text{and}\ \bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}E_k=\{3\}$$

Any suggestions to find the sets, I can't think of anything.

Comment: $E_1=\mathbb{R}$ and $E_k=(3-\frac{1}{k},3+\frac{1}{k})~\forall~k\geq2$.

Comment: Thanks, @Marcos :).

Answer (score 1):

$
E_k=
\begin{cases}
 \mathbb{R}&\text{if}\, k=1\\
 \{3\}&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$